# Adding key pair values into a dict missing

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, output, infinite-loop

I have been trying to add key values of a list into a dict whereas the key is the amount of times X is repeated in the list, and the value is X itself.

```
my_list = ["apple", "cherry", "apple", "potato", "tomato", "apple"]
my_grocery = {}
while True:
    try:
        prompt = input().upper().strip()
        my_list.append(prompt)
    except EOFError:
        my_list_unique = sorted(list(set(my_list)))
        for _ in my_list_unique:
            my_grocery[my_list.count(_)] = _
            #print(f'{my_list.count(_)} {_}')
        print(my_grocery)
        break
```

The expected output was:

```
{3: APPLE, 1: CHERRY, 1: POTATO, 1: TOMATO}
```

The the actual output received was:

```
{3: 'APPLE', 1: 'TOMATO'}
```

Does anyone have any idea why is that

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. You should use the words as the keys, and the counts as the values.

Comment: FYI there's a built-in `collections.Counter()` that will do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you couldn't have duplicated keys in dict, in your case it's "1", you can use Counter for vise versa key-value savings occurrences of each product type

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = []

while True:
    try:
        prompt = input().strip()
        if not prompt:
            break
        my_list.append(prompt)
    except EOFError:
        break

item_counts = Counter(my_list)

print(item_counts)
```

> Counter({'tomato': 2, 'apple': 2, 'mango': 1})

Answer (score 1):

As already notes you can't have duplicate keys so the product should be used as the key. Without using the collections module :

```
my_list = ['apple', 'cherry', 'apple', 'potato', 'tomato', 'apple']

my_grocery = {}


for entry in my_list:
    my_grocery[entry] =  my_grocery.get(entry, 0) + 1
            
print(my_grocery)
```

gives:

```
{'apple': 3, 'cherry': 1, 'potato': 1, 'tomato': 1}
```